# Call parameter constructor from default constructor without using this keyword

Tags: java, constructor

I know that we can call a constructor from another constructor of the same class using the this keyword. But is it somehow possible to call the parameter constructor from within the default constructor without using `this`?

I've tried:

```
class Example
{
    int x;

    public Example()
    {
         Example obj = new Example(2); 
    }

    public Example(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

}
```

But this doesn't let me assign value to `x` through the parameter constructor unless I use a getter method to get value from obj object. Is there a way to assign value to `x` by calling the parameter constructor only without using this?
If not then why?

Why can't we do this?

```
Example(2);
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Our Professor asked us to think about it..if we can achieve calling a constructor from within another without using 'this'.

Comment: You can have some sort of `initialise` method that will be called by all constructors, but then you cannot have `final` fields so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: then it is perhaps better to think about it, instead of ask for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't.

Quoting JLS [section 8.8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> **It is a compile-time error for a constructor to directly or indirectly invoke itself through a series of one or more explicit constructor invocations involving `this`.**

You have to write:

```
public Example()
{
     this(2); // or this.x = 2
}
```

Comment: So there's no other way to call a constructor from the default one? Why is it a compile time error?

Comment: @HamzaBinAmin Ask yourself, does it really make sense to be able to do it? The point of a constructor is to create a single new instance. Not to create multiple sub-instances.

Comment: But shouldn't something like Example(2) be the same as this(2)?

Comment: @HamzaBinAmin Well it would be but instead of using the the class-name, you use the `this` keyword. Only the syntax is different in this case and, in Java, the latter was chosen.

Comment: I still have a little confusion though. By a "series of explicit invocations involving this", do we mean both the constructor using this to call eachother? Because in this case I only wanted to call the parameter one through default so why would it lead to a compile time error?

Comment: @HamzaBinAmin It basically means that you can't construct a new instance while you are already constructing one. The arguments do not matter, what matters is a constructor can't invoke itself.